# Can I store my mountain bike + suspension hanging from the front wheel for the winter (in an unheated garage)?

Tags: storage

Switched over to my winter bike to keep my favorite away from the salt.

Can I hang my bike by the front wheel for the winter?  Will be in my unheated storage-room/garage/shed.  My ownly real concern is the suspension.  I have a Rockshox XC 32 shock.

Edit: The average daily low in January should be about -15 C (5 F) the record low was -40 C (-40 F).

Comment: Good question. I've stored all sorts of bikes by the front wheel, but never one with suspension.

Comment: Yeah, and unheated is not a problem.  The question is whether hanging such that the shocks are in stress like that for months would cause trouble -- damage the seals or some such.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but if clearance is an issue, you can likely take your wheel and/or fork off and hang by handle bars if you find pulling on the shock could cause damage.

Comment: What temperature will the garage go down to?

Comment: @cmannett85 -- The temperature doesn't matter.  A bicycle can handle any temperature an automobile can, and lower.

Comment: @cmannett85 Updated with temperature info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [product page](http://www.sram.com/rockshox/products/xc-32-tk), [manual](http://cdn.sram.com/cdn/farfuture/AKEpKBkwf1phnUAwnVJbe9et_anfKPI8CGLBb-59pw0/mtime:1344376749/sites/default/files/techdocs/2013_rockshox_spc_rev_a_0.pdf) and [warranty](http://cdn.sram.com/cdn/farfuture/skwUf0ZGRyfSPE45L8PLolJf0lUgUfXW3Z2eVhG3cpI/mtime:1341959041/sites/default/files/gen_0000000000562_sram_warranty_-_rev_e_0.pdf) do not mention anything about this. I think there should be no problem with storing the bike vertically or upside down. The oil will definitely stagnate at the top of the fork, on the seals. When you bring your bike to the ground you'll probably need to cycle the suspension 10 to 20 times in order to make the oil go down and re-lubricate everything.

Regarding the possibility of stress on the suspension, there will not be any problem, unless of course you hang yourself from the bike being upside down :)

Answer (score 6):

Apart from the suspension: do you have hydraulic disc brakes?
Some of them have an open design that is prone to let air in the system if the bike isn't stored upright.

Comment: Negative, mechanical disks.

Answer (score 0):

My main concern in hanging by the front wheel is the rim. Rims / spokes are not made for

1. a permanent force
2. in this direction.

Depending on other parameters like the weight of the bike and the rim / spoke type, I would consider hanging the bike by the frame instead of the front wheel.

Comment: If you're worried about the effects on the wheel the you could periodically rehang it, partially rotating the wheel, to even out the stresses.

Comment: That is true. However, I do not want to worry about rehanging, which is the reason I use the frame.

Comment: Would the force really be much different to leaving it standing - something most people wouldn't worry about.  You're applying a tensile force rather than a compressive, but how does this compare to the tension already in the spokes?

Comment: To put it simple, IMHO, wheels are in general "weaker" than frames. Agreeing with you and extending what you said, having the bike just standing on the ground instead of hanging it by the wheel is the alternative the wheels prefer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Dual Shocks like Revo hold positive and negative Air pressure. It doesn't matter how you store it. There is far more pressure on the valves if you sit on it.
Shocks are designed to withstand crazy forces. But it a good idea to wait a couple of minutes after turning it the right way so the oil can go back. There is not much oil in it anyway.